# Need help to understand a lemma of Doob Meyer Decomposition( Total inaccessible case)

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

I am studying the Doob Meyer Decomposition theorem. The resource I am following is Prof.Phillip Protter's textbook:[Stochastic Integration and Differential Equations](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540003137).

My questions relate to one of the lemmas in the Doob-Meyer Decompositions section on page 108. The statement of this lemma is:(or you could find this lemma on Prof. Richard Bass's paper: ['The Doob-Meyer Decomposition Revisited'](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/doobmeyer-decomposition-revisited/CADDAB1D45AB79DEF08980A4A087DA80).lemma 2.5 on page 4)

Choose and fix a $\nu\in\mathbb{Z}_+$, and let $D_n = \{k2^{-n}: 0\leq k2^{-n}\leq \nu\}$

$\bf{Lemma 2.}$ Let $T$ be a totally inaccessible stopping time. For $\delta > 0$, let $R(\delta) = \sup_{t\leq\nu} P(t\leq T\leq t+\delta|\mathcal{F}_t)$. Then $R(\delta)\rightarrow 0$ in probability as $\delta\rightarrow 0$.

I list the following three questions:

(1) Within the proof, it defines the following stopping times $$S_n(\delta) = \inf_{t}\{t\in D_n, P(t\leq T\leq t+\delta|\mathcal{F}_t)>a\}\wedge\nu$$

$$\bar{S}(\delta) = \inf_{n} S_n(\delta)$$
$$S = \sup_n \bar{S}(\frac{1}{n})$$
I couldn't see why $S$ here is accessible on $\{S =T\}$.

(2)It is not very clear to me why the inequality on the top of page 109 holds: for large n, $$P(E\{\mathbb{1}_{S_n(\delta)\leq T\leq S_n(\delta)+\delta}|\mathcal{F}_{S_n(\delta)}\} > a)\geq \epsilon$$
My thought on this is, it requires some sort of a.s right continuity of $f(t) :=E\{\mathbb{1}_{t \leq T\leq t+\delta}|\mathcal{F}_{t}\}$, but I don't see why this is true.

(3)Based on Richard Bass' [paper](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/canadian-mathematical-bulletin/article/doobmeyer-decomposition-revisited/CADDAB1D45AB79DEF08980A4A087DA80) as I mentioned above(proof of lemma 2.5 on page 4), it claims 
$$\text{from }P(E\{\mathbb{1}_{S_n(\delta)\leq T\leq S_n(\delta)+\delta}|\mathcal{F}_{S_n(\delta)}\} > a)\geq \epsilon\text{ to }P(E\{\mathbb{1}_{\bar{S}(\delta)\leq T\leq \bar{S}(\delta)+\delta}|\mathcal{F}_{\bar{S}(\delta)}\} > a)\geq \epsilon$$

and

$$\text{from }P(E\{\mathbb{1}_{\bar{S}(\delta)\leq T\leq \bar{S}(\delta)+\beta}|\mathcal{F}_{\bar{S}(\delta)}\} > a)\geq \epsilon\text{ to }P(E\{\mathbb{1}_{S\leq T\leq S+\beta}|\mathcal{F}_{S-}\} > a)\geq \epsilon\text{ to }$$
it use the remark 2.4 twice. This remark also appears as the lemma on page 107 in the Phillip Protter's [book](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540003137). It is also not very clear to me how this remark is helpful making the above two arguments.

Since I don't understand the proof very well, I have to apologize that my questions maybe not specific enough and unorganized. Please feel free to leave comments and thank you very much!